# ask ffmpeg subtitle and watermark on debian8 with no loss quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

please help for my case i have trouble on here for ffmpeg i use the command :

```
ffmpeg -i whiskey.mkv -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset veryslow -vf "movie=logo.png[wm];[in][wm]overlay=0:0,subtitles=whiskey.srt[out]" whiskey2.mp4
```

but get error

```
root@:~/ffmpeg# ffmpeg -i whiskey.mkv -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 2
8 -preset veryslow -vf "movie=logo.png[wm];[in][wm]overlay=0:0,subtitles=whiskey
.srt[out]" whiskey2.mp4
ffmpeg version N-80522-ge0faad8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration:
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100
  libavformat    57. 38.102 / 57. 38.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 46.102 /  6. 46.102
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
Unrecognized option 'crf'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

If you have any command for encode watermark + sub with no loss quality please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

## No libx264 support

You're attempting to use the encoder libx264 but your `ffmpeg` was not configured to support this encoder. Your `configure` line is blank, but it requires `--enable-libx264` & `--enable-gpl` to use libx264.

The easiest way to fix this is to [download a static build of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/): it will support libx264.

## No "loss of quality"

Filtering requires re-encoding, but you're attempting to use options that will make a lossy output.

If you really want no quality loss you have to make a lossless output, but most users don't really want this because the file will be huge and not all players/devices may support it. For a lossless output using libx264 use `-crf 0`.

What you probably actually want is lossy but with a good enough quality that you can't tell that is isn't technically lossless. For this use `-crf 18`.

Your command has extra, useless options. A cleaned up example is:

```
ffmpeg -i whiskey.mkv -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay,subtitles=whiskey.srt" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow output.mp4
```

If the input audio is compatible with MP4 container add `-c:a copy` to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio instead of re-encoding it.

#### Also see:

- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Comment: `you tell me for ./configure --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl` but <br/>after that we have confirmate License: GPL version 2 or later
`Creating config.mak, config.h, and doc/config.texi...
config.h is unchanged
config.asm is unchanged
libavutil/avconfig.h is unchanged
libavcodec/bsf_list.c is unchanged
libavformat/protocol_list.c is unchanged`

Comment: after try on this source : https://www.assetbank.co.uk/support/documentation/install/ffmpeg-debian-squeeze/ffmpeg-debian-jessie/ we have new problem `[aac @ 0x12e3580] element type mismatch 1 != 0` and ` [AVFilterGraph @ 0x12e2be0] No such filter: 'subtitles'
Error configuring filters.`

Comment: @osiarabfisla The subtitles filter requires `ffmpeg` to be compiled with `--enable-libass`. Why don't you use the static build as I suggested? The link you followed installs 2.7.2 which is outdated. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile on Ubuntu/Debian](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) if you must compile.